# IIS: failed to resource: net:: err_http2_protocol_error when loading JS files

Tags: iis, asp.net-mvc-5, iis-7

Some of the users on our website hosted on IIS7  intermittently encounter  net::err_http2_protocol_error on some JS files on the initial loading of the website.

[image: Console of user]

When they try to right-click the filename and open it in a new tab it loads the file.

They tried to do it in different browsers but with same result.

I created the website using .NET MVC5

Comment: Disable the browser side antivirus and try again. Or disable bundling and minification when producing server side artifacts.

Comment: You can refer to: https://forums.iis.net/t/1217362.aspx?Not+able+to+load+Website+successfully